# Cannot Access Vector in C++ Dungeon Text Game

Tags: c++, function, class, pointers, vector

Intro:
So my final project for this semester is to create a dungeon game that the player inputs the choices he/she has to make on the terminal and the output is his/her current status (e.g. current health, shield, damage, current room, etc). The dungeon is made up of rooms (2-dimensional, so the player could go up, down, right, left depending on the map) and the rooms have objects in them, including Monsters, NPCs, Items. Player can choose to interact with the objects (fight monsters, buy from NPCs or pick up Items) or move to another room. The professor has given us the classes' header files, and we have to simply write the cpp files for it.

Classes, members, and methods (that has to do with the problem):

1. Room - it has private members `Room* upRoom, downRoom, leftRoom, rightRoom` `int index` `vector<Object*> objects` and it basically just a linked list but 2-dimensional. Every room has its own index and vector of object pointers (might point to Item, Monster or NPC). To access the index of the room, use `getIndex()` function that returns the index. To access the vector objects, use `getObjects()` function that returns the vector.
2. Object - the base and abstract class, it has a private member `string name`, and access name using getName function. There's also a virtual function that deals with different interactions with the Player based on different children classes of Object.
3. Item - derived from Object, its private members are `int shield, health, attack` that could increase the player's states when picked up.
4. Game Character - derived from Object, its private members are `int currentHealth, maxHealth, attack, shield` (basically the status of a character)
5. Monster - derived from Game Character.
6. NPC - derived from Game Character, it has private members `string script` `vector<Item> items` items are what the player could buy from the NPC.
7. Player - derived from Game Character, it has a private member `Room* currentRoom` a pointer that points to the player's current room. We can access currentRoom using `getCurrentRoom()` function.
8. Dungeon - the dungeon itself, it has private members `Player player` `vector<Room> rooms` that make up the whole game. It has functions like `runDungeon` `createRoom()` and `createPlayer`. The main.cpp only consists of `runDungeon`.

So back to the problem:
In the `createRoom()` function, I declared all the things I want in the map and pushed back to `vector<Room> rooms`, which is a private member of Dungeon. For example:

```
void Dungeon::createRoom(){
        //create monster
        Monster zombie("Zombie", 50, 50, 10); //the ints are just the states

        //create commodities
        Item beef("Beef", 69, 0, 30);
        Item banana("Banana", 15, 0, 5);
        Item deagle("Deagle", 0, 59, 0);

        //create NPC
        NPC vick("Vick", "Hello there! I'm Vick the monkey.", {banana, deagle});

        //create rooms
        Room zero(0, {&vick}); //contains index and vector<Object*> objects
        Room one(1, {&beef, &zombie})

        //linking rooms together
        zero.setRightroom(&one);
        one.setLeftroom(&zero);

        //finally pushing back the rooms declared in this function to vector<Room> rooms
        rooms.push_back(zero);
        rooms.push_back(one);
}
```

There'a a function called displayRoom() which is to print out the room index and all the objects inside it.

```
void Dungeon::displayRoom(){
        //print out current room index, this works fine
        cout << player.getCurrentRoom()->getIndex << endl;

        //print out current room's first object's name, this won't work
        cout << player.getCurrentRoom()->getObjects().at(0) << endl;

        //print out current room's vector<Object*> size, and it always print 0
        cout << player.getCurrentRoom()->getObjects().size() << endl;
}
```

So my problem is that the vector full of object pointers disappears. Does declaring objects inside a function and pushing them back to a private member which other functions could access work? If not, is there a solution that might help? Sorry for my bad English, I hope you understand. :)

Comment: Storing pointer to objects in a vector is a bad design. Why don't you store the objects themselves in the vector?

Comment: Instead of `vector<Object*>` consider `vector<unique_ptr<Object>>` ... since Object is an abstract base class.

Comment: @kebs: I can think of two reasons (which may or may not apply here, I haven't studied the code that carefully): the objects may be expensive to copy, and they may be of different classes derived from a common base. Keeping a container of pointers is not, of itself, bad design, but pointers require careful handling.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please look at the page on [minimal complete examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). My first impulse is to run your code to reproduce the error and then find it, but I see that in order to do that I must *write* much code which you have omitted. That's a lot of work for me, and the bug might be somewhere in that code.

Comment: `Room zero(0, {&vick});`  `one.setLeftroom(&zero);` ... you are storing pointers to local variables that no longer exist after the `Dungeon::createRoom()` finishes. This is not going to work.

Comment: @Beta Sure, you are right of course, there are some use cases. But this is typically a code smell, and it leads to bad code most of the time with "beginner" programmers (as in the present case).

Answer (score 2):

The variables you defined in `createRoom` have lifetimes which end when the function returns. So pointers to them (`&vick`, `&beef`, `&zombie`, `&one`, `&zero`) are dangling at that point, and any use of them is undefined behavior.

To create objects which live past the end of the function where they were created, they need to be put in some other object or container, or created with `new` or `std::make_unique` or `std::make_shared`. You'll also want to choose one object which acts as the "owner" of each object with longer lifetime, to make sure there's simple logic in charge of cleaning up the objects' lifetime ends. Probably the `Dungeon` is the owner of the `Room`s, a `Room` is the owner of its `objects`, and an `NPC` is the owner of its stock for sale. (What about the player's inventory? Can a `Monster` have `Item`s? Maybe `GameCharacter` should have some inventory ownership logic?)

The raw pointers you've mentioned suggest you're expected to use `new` and `delete`, even though that's harder and not a great design. If you must use raw pointers, then every class which acts as an owner of other objects via raw pointers must carefully follow the Rule Of Five. In this case, copying most objects doesn't make sense, so you could delete the copy constructor and copy assignment and have move-only classes.

But if you're allowed to, it would be much easier to express ownership of pointers using `std::unique_ptr`. For example, change the `std::vector<Object*> objects;` in `Room` to a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Object>> objects;`. Note this should only be the "owning" pointers. The "right room", etc. properties can stay as raw pointers, since it's really the `Dungeon` which owns all rooms. But you do want to make sure those raw pointers are pointing at the `Room` objects held by the `Dungeon` and not copies of them.

Comment: Thanks for answering! However the rooms I created in the createMap() function were all pushed back into a vector of rooms. The vector of rooms is a private member of the dungeon class, so other functions also have access to it. Does the vector of rooms act as a container? Thanks

Comment: @lionelmayhem that part of the design is fine after you solve the ownership problem and remove the use of `&` and storing pointers to objects that go out of scope.

Answer (score 1):

So I did a simplified version of my code using `new` and I think it worked correctly:
main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "object.h"
#include "room.h"
using namespace std;

class dungeon{
private:
vector<room> rooms;
public:
    void createMap(){
        room zero, one;
        object* obj;
        obj = new object("sword");
        zero.addObjects(obj);
        obj = new object("knife");
        zero.addObjects(obj);
        obj = new object("zombie");
        one.addObjects(obj);
        obj = new object("titan");
        one.addObjects(obj);

        rooms = {zero, one};
    }
    vector<room> getRooms(){
        return rooms;
    }

};

int main(){
    dungeon Dungeon;
    Dungeon.createMap();
    cout << Dungeon.getRooms().at(0).getObjects().at(0)->getName() << endl;
}
```

room.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


class room{
private:
    int index;
    vector<object*> objects;
public:
    room(){}
    room(int index, vector<object*> objects){
        this->index = index;
        this->objects = objects;
    }
    int getIndex(){
        return index;
    }
    vector<object*> getObjects(){
        return objects;
    }
    void setIndex(int index){
        this->index = index;
    }
    void addObjects(object* obj){
        objects.push_back(obj);
    }
};
```

object.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class object{
private:
    string name;
public:
    object(string name){
        this->name = name;
    }
    string getName(){
        return name;
    }
};
```